# Adding only selected checkbox items to a Database?

Tags: php

My question is how to take a bunch of selected checkbox items and storing the ones only selected to the database.

The way the program runs now is with current data we are able to use a query to populate the data to the screen and towards the bottom of my code there are some special functions we call on the table rows and one of them is to create a hidden checkbox for each row. When the game is selected to yellow on the page the hidden checkbox is selected.

I want to select from a list of games. I want to save the ones that have a selected game into a database. After researching many other questions on this site similar I have still yet to get an answer. What I did was create a form on and a submit input type to submit to the DB. I am not familiar with how to make a php file to query the post data based on how I have the code written and push the wanted data into a new schema model.

I could truly use some help with this as I do not even know where to begin. Thank you all for your help in advance.

```
<?php $header= "Upcoming Games"; ?>

<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <?php
    require_once('dbBaseDao.php');
    require_once('dbGameDao.php');
    require_once('debug.php');

    //@Team: a GameDao is in the dbGameDao.php file and extends BaseDao. I have methods in there to make queries.
    //If you make any new queries, add it to the GameDao class (or *Dao class for new objects)
    $baseDao = new GameDao();

    $resultMw = $baseDao->{'getVsByRoundMW'}(3);
    $resultW = $baseDao->{'getVsByRoundW'}(3);
    $resultS = $baseDao->{'getVsByRoundS'}(3);
    $resultE = $baseDao->{'getVsByRoundE'}(3);

    //$baseDao->display($result);

    $round3 = Array();

    //make array of associative results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultMw)) $round3[] = $row;

    $keys = Array();

    $keys["Selection"] = "userSelection"; 
    $keys["Game ID"] = "gameID";          
    $keys["Name1"] = "Name1";
    $keys["Name2"] = "Name2";

    $functions = Array();

    $function["upsetPossible"] = "upsetPossible";    
    $function["userSelection"] = "checkbox";     
    $function["gameID"] =  "gameIdClass";    

?><!-- end PHP script --> 

<form action="selected.php" method="POST">              <!-- Test -->

<input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" />   <!-- Test -->


<div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="background-color:orange;">Midwest</a><br>
        <span class="numbers"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="unPlayed">
<?php

    foreach ($round3 as $row)
    {

        //@Team this print the columns and also calls the functions
        echo "<tr onclick=\"toggleColor(this);\">";     //tr tag modified by Krish
        foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key)
        {
            $rowName = $keys[$key];
            //@Team this checks if the function is in the functions array, and calls it if it exists in the document
            if (array_key_exists($rowName, $function) && is_callable($function[$rowName]))
            {
                //@Team: $params is something used to send parameters to the function
                //the only param is the row from the database, but is has access to all the columns
                //and can be called by name, e.g. $row['gameId']
                $params = Array();
                $params[] = $row;
                call_user_func_array($function[$rowName], $params);
            }
            //@Team: prints just the data in the row, for the column
            else echo "<td>$row[$rowName]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
</br>

<div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="background-color:orange;">West</a><br>
        <span class="numbers"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$round3 = Array();

    //make array of associative results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultW)) $round3[] = $row;
?>
<table class="unPlayed">
<?php
    //printHeaders($keys);
    foreach ($round3 as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr onclick=\"toggleColor(this);\">";         //tr tag modified by Krish
        foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key)
        {
            $rowName = $keys[$key];
            if (array_key_exists($rowName, $function) && is_callable($function[$rowName]))
            {
                $params = Array();
                $params[] = $row;
                call_user_func_array($function[$rowName], $params);
            }
            else echo "<td>$row[$rowName]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>

</br>
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="background-color:orange;">South</a><br>
        <span class="numbers"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$round3 = Array();

    //make array of associative results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultS)) $round3[] = $row;
?>
<table class="unPlayed">
<?php
    //printHeaders($keys);
    foreach ($round3 as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr onclick=\"toggleColor(this);\">";     //tr tag modified by Krish
        foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key)
        {
            $rowName = $keys[$key];
            if (array_key_exists($rowName, $function) && is_callable($function[$rowName]))
            {
                $params = Array();
                $params[] = $row;
                call_user_func_array($function[$rowName], $params);
            }
            else echo "<td>$row[$rowName]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
</br>

<div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="background-color:orange;">East</a><br>
        <span class="numbers"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$round3 = Array();

    //make array of associative results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultE)) $round3[] = $row;
?>
<table class="unPlayed">
<?php
    //printHeaders($keys);
    foreach ($round3 as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr onclick=\"toggleColor(this);\">";     //tr tag modified by Krish
        foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key)
        {
            $rowName = $keys[$key];
            if (array_key_exists($rowName, $function) && is_callable($function[$rowName]))
            {
                $params = Array();
                $params[] = $row;
                call_user_func_array($function[$rowName], $params);
            }
            else echo "<td>$row[$rowName]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
</br>

<input type="submit" value="Update">

</submitb>
</form>


<?php function printHeaders($keys)
{
    echo "<tr class=\"header\">";
    foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key) echo "<td>$key</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
}

function upsetPossible($params)
{
    echo "<td>";
    echo $params["upsetPossible"] == "1" ? "Yes" : "No";
    echo "</td>";
}

function checkbox($params)              //Added by Krish
{
    echo "<td>";
    $id = $params["gameID"];
    echo "<input id=\"$id\" type=\"checkbox\" style=\"display:none\">";
    echo "</td>";
}

function gameIdClass($params)           //Added by Krish
{
    echo "<td class=\"gameID\">";
    echo $params["gameID"];
    echo "</td>";
}

?>
```

Image of selecting games:
http://s28.postimg.org/50yo5a0jx/Screen_Shot_2014_03_23_at_2_43_27_PM.png

Answer (score 0):

You have two options/solutions:

Make an Ajax-Request if the JS-Function **toggleColor** is fired, otherwise you must add an hidden input-element to send it over an POST Request.

**mysql_*** is **Deprecated** use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I tried doing was adding a form and in that form I created an name action and method POST. Within each checkbox I created a value of an array gamesSelected and made sure that all values of true for checkbox would be stored in the array. Any idea where I can go from here?